# I'm unsure on what the issue is when deploying my ruby on rails application to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have built a ruby on rails application that works perfectly on my local dev environment. I'm trying to deploy it to heroku. My CI/CD pipline informs me that everything has run and has built. However when I try to access the page I get the following error.

[image]

The logs don't make much sense to me, so would someone be able to help me?

```
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329065+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:5:in `require_relative'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329077+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:5:in `block in <main>'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329090+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329103+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329116+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329129+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329142+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329155+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329168+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329181+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329194+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329207+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329220+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:38:in `start'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329232+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329245+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329258+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329271+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329284+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329297+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329310+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329323+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329336+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329348+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329361+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.329374+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:6:in `<main>'
2022-12-07T18:20:21.513425+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-12-07T18:20:21.569546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-12-07T18:20:21.572883+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-12-07T18:20:27.250273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2022-12-07T18:20:31.591717+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2022-12-07T18:20:31.591745+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 7.0.4 application starting in production
2022-12-07T18:20:31.591746+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
2022-12-07T18:20:32.603915+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604685+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:25:in `on_file_autoloaded': expected file /app/app/jobs/example_job.rb to define constant ExampleJob, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604697+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604699+00:00 app[web.1]: raise Zeitwerk::NameError.new("expected file #{file} to define constant #{cpath}, but didn't", cref.last)
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604711+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604728+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:31:in `require'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604742+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `const_get'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604756+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `cget'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604771+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:169:in `block in actual_eager_load_dir'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604785+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:40:in `block in ls'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604799+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `each'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604813+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `ls'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604828+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:164:in `actual_eager_load_dir'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604842+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604855+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `each'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604869+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `block in eager_load'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604884+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `synchronize'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604898+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `eager_load'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604912+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:296:in `block in eager_load_all'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604925+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:294:in `each'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604939+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:294:in `eager_load_all'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604953+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:74:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604967+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604980+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.604994+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605007+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605021+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605035+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605049+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605064+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605077+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605091+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605105+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605118+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605132+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605147+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605162+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:7:in `<main>'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605176+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:5:in `require_relative'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605190+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:5:in `block in <main>'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605203+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605217+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605230+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605244+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605258+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605271+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605286+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605299+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605313+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605327+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605341+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:38:in `start'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605358+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605372+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605387+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605400+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605415+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605429+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605443+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605458+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605472+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605486+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605501+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.605527+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:6:in `<main>'
2022-12-07T18:20:32.789481+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-12-07T18:20:32.849001+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-12-07T18:20:35.959337+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=book-review-app-1.herokuapp.com request_id=efb13321-b44e-4094-b31b-7e8f7937843f fwd="78.18.88.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-12-07T18:20:36.369851+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=book-review-app-1.herokuapp.com request_id=fdac1969-bc20-4ee8-9cbd-fb2dc49d061b fwd="78.18.88.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-12-07T18:34:32.202811+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=book-review-app-1.herokuapp.com request_id=dc080b47-b4c6-4f18-bbe7-a52918a2276b fwd="78.18.88.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-12-07T18:34:32.485141+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=book-review-app-1.herokuapp.com request_id=a95c315e-b461-48e0-ba1f-5dff9b728c74 fwd="78.18.88.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-12-07T18:42:42.437384+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=book-review-app-1.herokuapp.com request_id=9a477568-33a4-48c2-92dd-9fd2ff27c72d fwd="78.18.88.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-12-07T18:42:42.113747+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=book-review-app-1.herokuapp.com request_id=91c95dc3-8614-4c34-906b-aa4715eca822 fwd="78.18.88.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-12-07T18:42:52.090683+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-12-07T18:42:57.205143+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2022-12-07T18:43:00.924373+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-12-07T18:43:00.971586+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-12-07T18:43:00.041890+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2022-12-07T18:43:00.041928+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 7.0.4 application starting in production
2022-12-07T18:43:00.041928+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787451+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787935+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:25:in `on_file_autoloaded': expected file /app/app/jobs/example_job.rb to define constant ExampleJob, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787937+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787939+00:00 app[web.1]: raise Zeitwerk::NameError.new("expected file #{file} to define constant #{cpath}, but didn't", cref.last)
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787941+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787949+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:31:in `require'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787951+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `const_get'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787953+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `cget'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787962+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:169:in `block in actual_eager_load_dir'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787964+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:40:in `block in ls'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787966+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `each'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787968+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `ls'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787977+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:164:in `actual_eager_load_dir'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787979+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787981+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `each'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787983+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `block in eager_load'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787992+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `synchronize'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787994+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `eager_load'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.787995+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:296:in `block in eager_load_all'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788003+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:294:in `each'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788006+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:294:in `eager_load_all'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788007+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:74:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788010+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788017+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788020+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788038+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788041+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788041+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788041+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788041+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788042+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788042+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788042+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788044+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788051+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788053+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788061+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:7:in `<main>'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788062+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:5:in `require_relative'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788064+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:5:in `block in <main>'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788072+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788074+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788082+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788083+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788091+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788093+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788095+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788104+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788106+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788108+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788110+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:38:in `start'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788113+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788121+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788124+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788126+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788128+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788135+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788137+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788144+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788146+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788153+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788155+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
2022-12-07T18:43:00.788162+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have tried searching for solutoins on google and following youtube videos, but I can't get this working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem seems to be "expected file /app/app/jobs/example_job.rb to define constant ExampleJob, but didn't", what does `app/jobs/example_job.rb` look like?

Comment: "The logs aren't helping"—they're helping a lot more than the screenshot that just says "application error". The previous comment shows a particularly interesting snippet from the logs.

Comment: Your CI/CD pipeline should verify the application eager loads, please check https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-eager-loading.